# Insert an item in an array inside the array definition itself with a ternary operator, or push the item under a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, conditional-operator

I have an existing array in my codebase defined the next way

```
const tabs: Tabs[] = [
    {
      title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileA"),
      content: useContentA(),
      type: TYPE.A,
    },
    {
      title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileC"),
      content: useContentC(),
      type: TYPE.C,
    },
    [...more items...]
]
```

I have to insert an item in a position (doesn't matter at which one), if a condition is satisfied. I have reached to 2 alternatives and wanted to know which one is better and why.

1. Crete a const object outside the array, and then with a ternary operator insert it.

```
const bTab = {
    title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileB"),
    content: useContentB(),
    type: TYPE.B,
}


[...other_code...]
const tabs: Tabs[] = [
    {
      title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileA"),
      content: useContentA(),
      type: TYPE.A,
    },
    
    ...(isAvailable("titleB") ? [bTab] : []),


    {
      title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileC"),
      content: useContentC(),
      type: TYPE.C,
    },
    [...more items...]
]
```

2. Push the object directly to the array

```
[...same_array_definition...]

const bContent = useContentB()
if (isEnabled("titleB"))
   tabs.push({
    title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileB"),
    content: bContent,
    type: TYPE.B,
})
```

I've tested both of them and they work fine, but I was wandering which approach is better. I like more solution 1 because it seems more intuitive (in my opinion), but I don't know if inserting ([]) at the "else" clause is a bit "ugly" or can do any harm to the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use option 1 always. but I keep the logic out and just pass the variable to the array like this

```
const bTab = {
    title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileB"),
    content: useContentB(),
    type: TYPE.B,
}

const val = isAvailable("titleB") ? [bTab] : [];

const tabs: Tabs[] = [
    {
      title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileA"),
      content: useContentA(),
      type: TYPE.A,
    },
    
    ...val,


    {
      title: getTitle("generalSettings.getTileC"),
      content: useContentC(),
      type: TYPE.C,
    },
    [...more items...]
]
```